# Makefile not finding the include file

Tags: makefile

I Have a folder structure like this.

Gif_Utility

-> Makefile

-> include ( all .h files are over here)

-> Src ( all .c files are over here).

I am writing a makefile.

```
Makefile

VPATH = src:include
INC = -I  ./include

gif_objects = gif_display.o \
           gif_lzw.o \
           gif_read.o \
           sysm.o \
           x86_main.o


gif_display.0 : gif_display.c  
    gcc -I /export/home/joshis1/MakeTutorial/GIF_Utility/include -c $<

#gif_lzw.0 : gif_lzw.c
#   gcc $(INC) -c src/gif_lzw.c

#gif_read.0 : gif_read.c 
#   gcc -I ./include/ -c $< 

#sysm_main.0 : sysm_main.c 
#   gcc -I ./include/ -c $< 

#x86_main.0 : x86_main.c 
#   gcc -I ./include/ -c $< 


On command prompt:
$ make gif_display.o

cc    -c -o gif_display.o src/gif_display.c
src/gif_display.c:2:17: fatal error: sysm.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [gif_display.o] Error 1
```

On the other hand, If i do like this it compiles fine
$make 
-> this creates the gif_display.o

I don't know why it is throwing error on specifying the rule. Am I missing something, please help.

I am using Ubuntu machine to build my code.

Answer (score 2):

Your makefile has a `.0` (zero) suffix instead of the correct `.o` (letter oh).

When you run just `make` it attempts to build the first target in the Makefile, and so runs the recipe which contains the correct `-I` include path.  The fact that it produces an `.o` file, not a `.0` file, is acceptable to `make`, although I suppose it could at least print a warning in this scenario.

When you run `make gif_display.o` it uses Make's built-in productions for `.o` files, which do not contain your include path.

Given that `make` already has built-in rules for `.o` files, your rules are basically superfluous.  It would be better to just add the `-I include` parameter to the default rules, with something like

```
CFLAGS += -I include
```

So the entire Makefile could be as simple as this:

```
VPATH = src:include
CFLAGS += -I  ./include

gif_objects = gif_display.o \
           gif_lzw.o \
           gif_read.o \
           sysm.o \
           x86_main.o
```

I don't see anything to alert your Makefile to changes in `.h` files, so you might want to add a separate dependency for that.  If you just have a few shared header files between all your object files, maybe this will be all you need:

```
$(gif_objects): $(wildcard include/*.h)
```

This basically makes the `include` component of the `VPATH` superfluous.